# Converting String Expression to Float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am sorry if this question has been answered already, I just couldn't find it.
I have scraped a table with `pandas.read_html`. In the table, I have a couple of expressions I am interested in the format of "20.15 X 200", where the type is a string. I want to convert them to floats in order to make the multiplication and later compare the values. The issue I have is that the expressions are with the "X" sign for multiplication and I am not able to find any information ho to convert such an expression.

When I try the function to `float()` I get - `ValueError: could not convert string to float`.

Comment: You're looking for a way of _evaluating_ an expression - that's something entirely different from converting a string to a float using `float`. A simple way to do this could be `eval("20.15 X 200".replace('X', '*'))`.

Comment: That works. Thank you!